# Show div element from top to show its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an div element with class panel. What I want is when I click an anchor tag with class `open` then it should show a div container with class `panel` and slide it down.

In my current code I have two links with class `open`. When I click any of them then it animates the panel. But when I click the bottom anchor tag then I cannot see the element until I scroll up.

How can I make this animation possible so that which ever link I click anywhere on page then I must see panel to be animated and shown?

Here is my code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/buHJ5/)

Comment: This can be done using `$(document).scrollTop()`. Refer to my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11328527/500725)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways come to my mind,

first: u set panel's CSS position:fixed; than user can see panel from everywhere,

[this is DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/buHJ5/1/)

or second way: u set multiple conditionals functions for each click

```
 $('.openTop').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.panel').animate({top:'300'},500).show();
 });
 $('.openBottom').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.panel').animate({top:'1000'},500).show();
});
```

Comment: Any other better way? Something that is done through javascript.

Comment: You could have a div and give it a @keyframe animation from a negative margin-top like `-10em` to `margin-top: 0` (or any value you wish).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a simple way using

```
$(document).scrollTop()
```

### JS:

```
$('.open').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var topVal = $(document).scrollTop() + 300;
    $('.panel').animate({top:'+='+topVal}).show();
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/buHJ5/5/)**